# How to keep myself logged in on PCs that are shares over a domain?

Tags: windows, windows-10, user-accounts, login, windows-domain

I'm in a broadcasting class at my school, and the classroom has a computer lab that consists of Dell Optiplexes and Dell Precisions. The Dell Precisions are used to edit video as they have Nvidea 2060s in them along with Intel's i9 processors.

Currently, it can take several hours to render videos due to the slow speed on a single Dell Precision, but recently, I've discovered that Adobe Media Encoder supports render farming. The only issue is that my account has to remain logged in the background to use the set of PCs to render farm. Using the Windows + L command, I can lock the PC so that my account is still running in the background. But after a few more students log in, it completely signs out my account, stopping all processes I have running.

Basically, is there a way I can make my user account stay logged in by default on several PCs in the background?

Comment: Do you mean the same computer gets several students logged in in turn, without them logging out? Are you sure that your account specifically gets _logged out_, and not that the encoder gets killed by the OS due to the system running out of RAM?

Comment: Basically, I log into the PC at the beginning of the day. Use it. When the hour is over, I hit Windows + L to lock it so my stuff runs in the background. Then, the next student logs in, and the next, and the next. Most students don't know about Windows + L and just lick sign out. Each of the systems have 32GB of 2666mhz DDR3 ram. I am the only one that uses the PCs for editing 9 out of 10 days, the average user in that class uses chrome and that's it. I don't think it's ram overload. Is there any way to see a log or something that could tell me if it is?

Comment: IT at my school is quite useless and actually, today, they messed up all the PCs I have pooled together for the use of render farming. They replaced all the Optiplex in the room and renamed all of the PCs, and in the process, renamed some of the PCs the same name as the Dell Precisions, so currently they cant log into the domain until they fix them. They claim the Optiplexes also cant handle Adobe Lightroom or Photoshop, which I've proved wrong several times by running it on a PC that was way slower than the Optiplexes. In middle school, I was essentially the schools tech support because IT

Comment: Was never around to fix anything. I currently plan on using Adobe Media Encoder to render multiple after effects compositions to each of the 4 Dell Precisions that are pooled. My next step is setting up a watch folder